# HTTP vs HTML Character Sets Affecting JS Includes

Tags: php, http, character-encoding, header

I'm changing a website to use the UTF-8 character set from iso-8859-1.

When i change this:

`<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' />`

to

`<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />`

It all appears to work fine and posting forms sends the data in UTF-8. Perfect.

But when i set this

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

The javascript includes break which i wasn't expecting. Obviously there is some 3rd party code in their that uses characters in iso-8859-1 encoding that doesn't change to utf-8 correctly. So fixing the javascript code itself is easy enough.

**HTTP Header Set to UTF-8 + HTML Content Type Set to UTF-8**

- Breaks javascript includes
- Affects the encoding of posting form data

As expected, it hints that everything is using UTF-8, however, it breaks the javascript include... It also only breaks the js include on FireFox. I tested this configuration on IE, Chrome and Opera and it works fine. For this reason i'm starting to think maybe FireFox is at fault here and this is a bug in the browser (though a simple fix for FireFox is to add chartset='iso-8859-1' to the script tag).

**HTTP Header set to iso-8859-1 + HTML Content Type Set to UTF-8**

- Does not affect javascript includes
- But does affect the encoding of posting form data

I was always under the impression that the HTTP header SHOULD overwrite any inconsistant character sets defined in the HTML header. However, it appears JS includes listen to the HTTP character set... while posting data ignores the HTTP header and listens to the HTML character set instead!?

**Can anybody explain why and is it supposed to happen this way or is it possibly a bug in FireFox 17.0.1?**

Comment: What exactly breaks with what error message?

Comment: Don't use php header you may get headers already sent error.

Comment: Don't worry about the breaking, that's not the question, the question is why the 2 different ways of changing character sets is and isn't affecting the javascript character set. i can fix the javascript error myself.

Comment: @faridmovsumov Got output buffering on... so can send headers when ever also it's sent before any output anyway ;)

Comment: Are you setting your file encoding to UTF-8? Eg the PHP/js files in question?

Comment: That's irrelevant. I know why the JS breaks... what i don't know is why the HTTP header affects it and the HTML one doesn't?

Comment: @faridmovsumov Then you need to solve that problem by outputting the header before any content. Not using `header` is not a solution, it's a problem.

Comment: Can you clearly specify what is what and how it breaks? What encoding are the files in, what header/meta tag are you setting and *how* does it break exactly? For each variation. The current explanation is too random to give a specific answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you can control the buffering, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php else, just alter the Javascript and make it UFT-8.

About the question... the php header controls the output sent by the server so, the PHP will alter the content. That META tag is just an info for the browser "be careful, this is UTF-8".

Comment: That still does not answer the question, "why the HTTP header affects the encoding of the JavaScript include and the HTML one doesn't affect it? Especially since the HTTP header SHOULD overwrite the one specified in the HTML."

Comment: So, you're saying that your [script src="**file.js**"] will have a different content? How can you check this? Maybe you get some elements from your HTML content via JS and that is the altered content.

Comment: Ok, so your js file is iso-8859-1? Again, how do you know that the js is altered? Can you post the js online and add here a link to it. I tried a test on my PC but maybe you have only SOME special chars.

Comment: The JS is not altered, the browser assumes it's in UTF-8 when it's not. Hence why it only breaks when i change the HTTP header of the HTML document. I want to know why the browser is changing the charset? I can't explain this in a simpler way i'm affraid.

Comment: Indeed, it's strange. Try `<script type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1"...` and check if that works.

Comment: That was the fix and only needed on one JS include. However, this problem only seems to exist in FireFox... it doesn't affect the others (opera, chrome etc) even IE works for once!

Comment: The HTTP/PHP header does not *control* the output encoding. It just specifies what the output is supposedly encoded in.